# How to read every row of CSV and invoke the value by a user function, and then save the result in an csv file?

Tags: python

```
import csv
import time
with open("AuthorName.csv", "rb") as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f, delimiter="\t")
    for line in enumerate(reader):
        time.sleep(2)
        print line[1]
```

The result is like:

```
['rhaf_hq']
['Digixp']
['bujhoapp']
['styhuang']
['mkasanm']
```

How can I invoke these lists in the function below: **Screen_names**

```
print json.dumps(get_user_profile(twitter_api, screen_names=["SocialWebMining"]), indent = 1 )
```

Comment: Do you have any code you can show? Please read [this](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and [this](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to know how to put together a good question on SO.

Comment: Thanks for your consideration!

Answer (score 0):

Here's a sample function that seems to do what you asked.
It works as follows:

1. Open your current file (fileName)
2. Store said file's content into a list (values[])
3. Create the file you want to write in (newValues.csv)
4. Create an object to write with (valueWriter)
5. write each value from your list into the new file (the writerow() function)

.

```
import csv

def make(fileName):
    with open(fileName) as file:
        values = []
        #Putting all your file's data in a list
        for each in file:
            each = each.strip()
            values.append(each)
    #Creating your new file
    with open('newValues.csv','w') as newFile:
        #creating a variable to write with
        valueWriter = csv.writer(newFile)
        #writing each individual value to your new file
        for each in values:
            valueWriter.writerow([each])
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply! It is a great help!

Comment: You're welcome! :) Did I find the answer you needed?

Comment: Yeah, part of it. I did not make problem clearly before.  I am not able to  invoke the lists in a function.  Please take my post new for your reference. Thanks!